# Is there any way to remove declaration?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I use a library which in its declaration file `index.d.ts` has:

```
declare namespace browser.runtime
{
    ...
    function sendMessage(message: any, options?: _SendMessageOptions): Promise<any>;
    function sendMessage(extensionId: string, message: any, options?: _SendMessageOptions): Promise<any>;
    ...
}
```

There is any way to remove those declarations? To be more precisely I want to remove `any` from it.

---

I know that I can add overload, but that doesn't satisfy me:

```
declare namespace browser.runtime
{
    function sendMessage(message: any, options?: _SendMessageOptions): Promise<unknown>;
}
```

Comment: Is the declaration file provided with the library? Or did you install it separately from @types/some-library?

Comment: It comes from `@types/*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type declarations.

- Create a new folder for your type declarations. You can use any name, for example `types`.
- Create a declaration file in this folder. You can use any name, for example `some-library.d.ts`. In your case, you can copy the file from `@types/some-library` and make your changes.
- Edit your TypeScript configuration. I assume you are using `tsconfig.json`. Add the following:

```json
"typeRoots": [
  "./types",
  "./node_modules/@types",
],
```

- You can uninstall `@types/some-library`.

Comment: Yes, that will work. But I will loose changes and updates made to original `@types/libs`.